# Prove the following identities ..complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I found this question on my Algebra book but i couldn't answer it
Can you please explain step by step
Prove the following identities ..explain its geometric meaning 
$|1+z_1\bar z_2|^2 + |z_1-z_2|^2 = (1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2)$

Comment: You're missing an exponent $2$, $\lvert 1 + z_1\overline{z}_2\rvert^2 + \lvert z_1 - z_2\rvert^2 = (1 + \lvert z_1\rvert^2)(1 + \lvert z_2\rvert^2)$. Then it is a simple expansion of $\lvert w\rvert^2 = w\overline{w}$.

Comment: @danielfisher but I am still confused about the left side never faced this before can you please simplify the left side step by step please

Comment: CHECK MY ANSWER

Comment: Thank you very much but I can't even give you reputation I am too new but I am really glad for your help

Comment: @AhmedEmad: It appears that you have created two accounts.  If you wish to have them merged, please [follow the instructions listed here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @AhmedEmad but you can accept the answer if you like by clicking the tick below the voteup option.

Answer (score 2):

Using $|z|^2=z\bar z$

we have L.H.S $$|1+z_1\bar z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2|^2=(1+z_1\bar z_2)(1+\bar z_1z_2)+(z_1-z_2)(\bar z_1-\bar z_2)$$

or $$1+z_1\bar z_2+\bar z_1z_2+|z_1|^2|z_2|^2+|z_1|^2-z_1\bar z_2-\bar z_1z_2+|z_2|^2$$

or $$1+|z_1|^2|z_2|^2+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$$

which is equal to R.H.S $$(1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2)$$

Comment: @BabakS. the photo in the discription section of your profile what is it.